# problem with drag and drop email in tomboy

Tags: 12.04, evolution, tomboy

When I click mail message in evolution and drag it into the open note either tomboy closes or comp freezes..
I have tried uninstall, restart multiple time it seems that the evolution plugin isnt working
I use tomboy to track communication at work: I write time of calls subjects etc,, drop email related to a particular project into the note and when discussing the project I have all the communication available to me in one note,
very very useful.
I just upgraded 2 laptops to 12.04 (actually both were clean install)
The same problem is present on both computers 
Compaq presario and Sony Viao

Comment: If anyone knows an app that suport drag and drop emails (any client will do) please tell me I miss it so much..I tried clawmail last night but there isnt a .dll and I have no knowlwdge of compiling. Iused evolution email purely for that drag and drop , so I guess I will uninstall and go back to thundirbird instead.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it, it only work if evolution is in pop protocol and notIMAP. I have reconfigured email account in pop and it now works again . I ticked leave a message copy on server
so they dont disappear from My imap account.